# Leaflet WMS JSON transparent rendering

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms

I am displaying from Geoserver a WMS layer into leaflet in a PNG Format:

```
    var app_coup = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8081/geoserver/cite/wms", {
        layers: 'cite:vnm_polbnda_adm3_2014_pdc',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
        version: '1.1.0',
        attribution: "test"
        });
```

After this, I query in JSON for a POP Up of the information of my labels:

```
/// Popup limite_inter_district
    var owsrootUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/geoserver/cite/wms';
    var defaultParameters = {
        service : 'WFS', //
        version : '2.0',
        request : 'GetFeature',
        transparent: true,
        typeName : 'cite:vnm_polbnda_adm3_2014_pdc',
        outputFormat : 'json',
        format_options : 'callback:getJson',
        SrsName : 'EPSG:4326'
    };
    var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);
    var URL = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters);
    var ajax = $.ajax({
        url : URL,
        dataType : 'json',
        jsonpCallback : 'getJson',
        success : function (response) {
        L.geoJson(response, {
                onEachFeature: function (feature, url) {
                    popupOptions = {maxWidth: 250};
                    url.bindPopup("<b>adm3_name:</b> " + feature.properties.adm3_name
                        ,popupOptions);
                }
            }).addTo(map);
        }
    });
```

I have the following question:

Why the polygons are displaying in blue when I been setting transparent to 'True'?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `transparent: true` for WMS call when result is returned as GeoJSON has no effect on style of layer display in Leaflet.

Layer display can be styled with `style` option when created with `L.geoJson` call. If no option is specified, polygons inherit default path styles (see https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#path), which means transparent interior and '#3388ff' color for boundary. This is what happened in your case.

If you want to disable boundary display, you have to define style option/function, where style `stroke` option is set to `false`.

In your case this would look like:

```
L.geoJson(response, {
  style: function(feature) {
    return {stroke: false};
  },
  onEachFeature: function (feature, url) {
    popupOptions = {maxWidth: 250};
    url.bindPopup("<b>adm3_name:</b> " + feature.properties.adm3_name
      ,popupOptions);
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks For the explanations @TomazicM